# Would Evacuation and Ambush Commander return all forests to their owners' hands?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Evacuation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Evacuation) returns all creatures to owners hands. [Ambush Commander](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ambush%20Commander) turns all forests into creatures. Would that mean that Evacuation would return all forests to their owners hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ambush Commander only affects its controller's Forests, but otherwise, yes.  Evacuation will return them to their owners' hands.

This doesn't come down to a single rules citation, but ultimately Creature Lands still count as creatures due to this rule:

> **608.2h** If an effect refers to certain characteristics, it checks only for the value of the specified characteristics, regardless of any related ones an object may also have.
>
> Example: An effect that reads “Destroy all black creatures” destroys a white-and-black creature, but one that reads “Destroy all nonblack creatures” doesn’t.

It does not matter that they are 'Creature Lands', the spell just cares that they are creatures.

Comment: Your citation is accurate; I've edited the language to be more certain and confident.